# How do I export functions from an ActiveX Control (.ocx) that are not in the main class?

Tags: c++, vb6, activex, export, ocx

I have a C++ DLL with 100+ exported functions which I want to transform into an OCX file. However, I only know how to export functions from an OCX which reside in the main class (called CmyCtrl by the Visual Studio 10 ActiveX control wizard) … by doing this:

```
BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CmyCtrl, COleControl)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CmyCtrl, "AboutBox", DISPID_ABOUTBOX, AboutBox, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
END_DISPATCH_MAP()
```

and using appropriate IDL definitions.

I'm not really keen on restructuring the whole large project and moving every single function definition (which are spread out across 20 or so files) into the class. Can I export functions from an OCX (with full support for Intellisense etc. in VB6, where the control will be used) which are not in the class? How do I do that and what do I have to keep in mind?

Comment: Surely you want to convert it to a DLL (not an OCX) - it will have to be an ActiveX DLL if you wish to use VB6

Comment: I actually mean an OCX file. This is actually a COM DLL, just a different extension. I have done this before, it works great with VB6. I just don't really know about the internals so I have to use the wizard-generated template.

Comment: The DLL file extension is used by convention for a COM DLL that doesn't serve controls (only simple classes).  Only name it OCX if it is a control library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a wizard somewhere to add a new "ATlObject" that mean create a ne class instantiable via COM. With this you can split your function in different classes. Supposing you have an ATLproject, when adding a new class this wizard should appear:
[image]

By creating a new ATL simple object you have another class with exported function in the classical COM way. If you want you can always export a function with dllexport, but in this case you cannot use COM to interface with your component. You can even call function exported with the dll ( ocx ) the regular way by using the strategy:

```
Private Declare Function MyFuncName Lib "yourocx.ocx" ([.. parameters]) As [Return type]
```

but it is probably not the way to go in your case.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know, but my question is meant like: Can I export functions which are in global namespace?

Comment: @FelixDombek couldn't you just wrap these function ? You can export them as you can do in any C dll ( __declspec(dllexport) ) but this is not the easy way to use your function from VB6/VB.NET ( even if possible )

Comment: Actually, VB6 doesn't work with `declspec(dllexport)`, one must use a .def file instead. But OK, I guess the answer to my question is simply  "no" as COM is inherently class-based.

Comment: @FelixDombek VB6 can, but I don't think is the way to go, I improved the reply.